# Analytical solution to MLE with constraint

Tags: maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution

Suppose *independent* random variables, $X\sim Binom(n,\theta_1)$ and $Y\sim Binom(n,\theta_2)$, with observed $x$ and $y$.

I'd like to find the MLE of $\theta$ under the joint likelihood $Pr(X=x,Y=y,X+Y=z)=Pr(X=x)Pr(Y=y)\mathbb1\{x+y=z\}$ subject to $\theta\leq c\in(0,1)$.

Any thoughts on obtaining an analytical solution for the MLE?

Comment: If you have a constraint $\theta\leq c$, then this seems like  [MAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation) estimation perhaps? (Also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_sum_variance_inequality) seems to say that unless $\theta_1=\theta_2$ your sum will not be binomial.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the variance inequality statement! You're right that Z is not binomial. What if the sum is not necessarily required to be binomial, but its partitions must be independent binomials? I've edited the OP. Also thank you for pointing out MAP estimation. It certainly looks like a viable option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like [MAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation) estimation rather than MLE, as your joint prior $p(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ is not uniform.

In other words, you have
\begin{align}p(\theta_1,\theta_2 \mid X_i,Y_j) & \propto p(X_i,Y_j\mid \theta_1,\theta_2) \,p(\theta_1,\theta_2) \\ &= p(X_i\mid \theta_1)\,p(Y_j\mid \theta_2)\,p(\theta_1,\theta_2) \\ &\propto p(X_i\mid \theta_1)\,p(Y_j\mid \theta_2)\,(\theta_1\in [0,1])\,(\theta_2\in [0,1])\,(\theta_1+\theta_2\leq c)\end{align}

For a particular set of $(X_i,Y_j)$ data, you could write out this joint (posterior) likelihood function for $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ and maximize it (or minimize the negative log likelihood).

This problem could be treated as a [constrained optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) over your feasible region. (For negative log likelihood, the objective function becomes infinite outside the feasible region, and the prior term is zero within the feasible region.)